# How to Read .mdb file using python 64 bit?

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc, mdbtools

i am getting filenot found error in pandasaccess

MDB tools are also not working

mdb-tables : The term 'mdb-tables' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mdb-tables .\Classes\Test-results.mdb

Pyodbc is working only on win 32 bit

similar one here [How to read from a 32 bit .mdb with 64 bit python and odbc driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539500/how-to-read-from-a-32-bit-mdb-with-64-bit-python-and-odbc-driver)

But still no answer for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pandas_access](https://pypi.org/project/pandas_access/) is a thin wrapper around MDBTools and MDBTools is really only intended for non-Windows platforms.

If you want to use pandas to work with an .mdb file in 64-bit Python under Windows then you need to install the 64-bit version of the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) and use the [sqlalchemy-access](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access) dialect for SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Thompson its unfortunate that i can't install 64-bit access database as i don' t have administrative previlages. Thanks for your inputs its useful

Comment: It is the responsibility of your IT department to provide you with the tools you need to perform your job.

Comment: I have downgraded my python to 32 bit, now i can be able read .mdb files using pyodc module. Thanks @gord Thompson